# LINQ to check each property of a list object to see if it's value is equal to a string

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list object that contains positions as properties in the object. I want to check to see if any of these properties are equal to a string (ie, "starter").  How can I do this via LINQ without having to check each position individually?

For instance if I have 18 positions as properties of the list item, and QB, RB and WR have the value "starter" I want those positions to be returned in the LINQ Query.

EXAMPLE:

```
Public class teamNeeds {
   public string QB {get; set;}
   public string RB {get; set;}
   public string WR {get; set;}
   public string TE {get; set;}
  .......etc, etc
} 

List<teamNeeds> needs = new List<teamNeeds>();
```

I pull in the info from a datatable for this team, there are various things it could be for each position---starter, backup, depth, etc...

In this instance I want to find all positions within the List having "Starter" as their value(ie, loop through the properties of the list item to find all properties with values = "Starter")

Comment: I added a more detailed example

Comment: Since LINQ deals with lists of items, and your example has only a single class, I think you will need to re-think your approach here. It's either that, or have 18 `if` statements to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You ushould normalize this design: `TeamNeeds` should have a collection of `Position`s (Name = "QB" etc, Value = "starter", ...). Much easier to query all positions where value equals "starter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a methodology using Reflection:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TeamNeeds> needs = new List<TeamNeeds>();

        TeamNeeds n1 = new TeamNeeds();

        n1.QB = "starter";

        TeamNeeds n2 = new TeamNeeds();

        n2.RB = "starter";

        needs.Add(n1);
        needs.Add(n2);

        foreach (var need in needs)
        {
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> list = need.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => (string)prop.GetValue(need, null) == "starter");
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                //This will give you the propertyName
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class TeamNeeds
{
    public string QB { get; set; }
    public string RB { get; set; }
    public string WR { get; set; }
    public string TE { get; set; }
}
```

However, would this design work better for you:

```
class Program
{
    static void BetterMain(string[] args)
    {
        List<TeamV2> teamList = new List<TeamV2>();

        foreach(var team in teamList)
        {
            List<Player> starters = team.playerList.Where(p => p.isStarter == true).ToList();
            starters.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.positionName));
        }        
    }
}

public class TeamNeeds
{
    public string QB { get; set; }
    public string RB { get; set; }
    public string WR { get; set; }
    public string TE { get; set; }
}


public class TeamV2
{
    public List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();
}

public class Player
{
    public bool isStarter;
    public bool positionName;
}
```

Comment: Argh... wouldn't it be better just to have a better designed `TeamNeeds` class?

Comment: @code4life Agreed :) Was going to be editing a better design recommendation into my answer

Comment: Well, I have these classes auto-mapped to SQLite tables, so I can read, write and query them without having to do any assignments.  What would you suggest for making it easier to work with?

Comment: Were these tables ones that you generated? You could take TeamNeeds passed as an overload to to create List<Player> from it for in memory work and remap it back out as a return type from a method in TeamV2.

Comment: @jordanhill123 I appreciate the redesign attempt, but that isn't really going to be sufficient.  There are 8 or 9 different possibilities regarding the needs of the team for each position, not just starter or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152357/discussion-between-jordanhill123-and-matt-e).

Answer (score 1):

So you need this?

```
string s = "Starter";
var result = needs
    .Where(t => t.QB == s || t.RB == s || t.WR == s || t.TE == s...)
    .ToList();
```

And only problem is, you do not want to write 18 conditions? You can build the expression dynamically:

```
Type type = typeof(teamNeeds);
Expression cond = Expression.Constant(false);
ParameterExpression par = Expression.Parameter(type);
ConstantExpression ces = Expression.Constant("Starter");
foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        Expression prop = Expression.Property(par, property.GetMethod);
        Expression eq = Expression.Equal(prop, ces);
        cond = Expression.OrElse(cond, eq);
    }
}

Func<teamNeeds, bool> condFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<teamNeeds, bool>>(cond, par).Compile();

var result = needs.Where(condFunc).ToList();
```

Nice thing is, if you need to run the conditions on the server query, you just change one line:

```
Expression<Func<teamNeeds, bool>> condFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<teamNeeds, bool>>(cond, par);
```

now you can use it in IQueryable.

Comment: Yes, I am not wanting to write out 18 conditions, I know there has to be a way to do this in a much easier way.

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done with LinQ it's not the most elegant and efficient way. I think it is more appropriate to use a simple foreach.

```or-tag-here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<teamNeeds> list = new List<teamNeeds> {
            new teamNeeds("abc", "starter", "ka", "starter")
        };

        //iterate over list and reflect properties
        foreach (var item in list) {
            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if(prop != null && prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString() == "starter")
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item, null));
            }
        }

        //same via linq      
        var selectedViaLinq = list.Select(item =>
        {
            return item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.GetValue(item, null) == "starter").ToList();
        }).ToList();


    }
}
public class teamNeeds
{
    public teamNeeds(string qb, string rb, string wr, string te)
    {
        QB = qb;
        RB = rb;
        WR = wr;
        TE = te;
    }

    public string QB { get; set; }
    public string RB { get; set; }
    public string WR { get; set; }
    public string TE { get; set; }
}
```